# Why is Google Chrome emptying my search bar in MediaWiki?

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome, mediawiki

*This is a saga that begun with*

- *[Adding extra search text to a MediaWiki search query using InputBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205405/adding-extra-search-text-to-a-mediawiki-search-query-using-inputbox) and continued with*
- *[PHP function is not defined error and syntax error of misplaced `</p>` in generated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685237/php-function-is-not-defined-error-and-syntax-error-of-misplaced-p-in-generate).*

I have created a JavaScript to enter text into a MediaWiki search box depending on check box selections. This now works in Firefox and Internet Explorer. But not in **Google Chrome**.

In Chrome, the search box is correctly filled (with the aforementioned JavaScript) but the search box blanks (empties) when the search button is pressed. This means that the search URL is also blanked which in turn means that only the default MediaWiki search page is shown.

What is Chrome doing with **[the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685237/php-function-is-not-defined-error-and-syntax-error-of-misplaced-p-in-generate/10714755#10714755)** that FF and IE are not - and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my PHP code, I embedded this JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function appendAndSubmit(){var platform1 = document.getElementById('p1').checked;var platform2 = document.getElementById('p2').checked;var text = document.getElementById('searchboxInput').value;if (platform1 * platform2 >0) text = text + ' "Applies to=Platform 1.0" "Applies to=Platform 2.0"';else if (platform1) text = text + ' "Applies to=Platform 1.0"';else if (platform2) text = text + ' "Applies to=Platform 2.0"';document.getElementById('searchboxInput').value = text;document.forms['searchform'].submit();}</script>
```

The variable `text` was defined as what was in the search form. So I simply changed the last part:

```
document.forms['searchform'].submit();
```

to

```
text.submit();
```

It works, but I don't know why.